# Parse text from html website using webbrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to create a form that acceses a ticket management system website in order to show me in a windows form application, in some textboxes, info like Created by:, Ticket Title, Created at, and so on.
I tried to set a filter to start from a certain line:

```
var ticketLines = codes.Where(m => m.StartsWith("<TD style=\"WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 110px\" class=hb-table-cell>"));
```

after generating the html:

```
var codes = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gridBox").InnerHtml.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(m => m.Trim()).ToList();
```

For this, i have created a list in which i will ad certain info`s i need:

```
List<string> ticketTitles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in ticketLines)
            {   
                //select the line from which you want to start scrapping
                int y = codes.IndexOf(line);
                //ticket title
                ticketTitles.Add(codes[y + 1].Substring(codes[y + 1].IndexOf(">") + 1, codes[y + 1].Length - codes[y + 1].IndexOf(">") - 6));
                //created at
                ticketTitles.Add(codes[y+2].Substring(codes[y+2].IndexOf(">")+1, codes[y+2].Length - codes[y+2].IndexOf(">") - 6 )); 
            }
```

in my form i have a 'login' button and a 'generate' button. The generate button activates the page by entering the specific ticket id.

My progress until now is the creation of the automatic login button, without this one you cannot enter the website at a certain ticket number.

How can I show my elements in a textbox? can someone explain to me the process?
Someone tried to help me and saved into a txt all the code in this form:

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 416px; HEIGHT: 134px" class=hb-ui-grid>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 416px; HEIGHT: 23px" class=hb-ui-grid-header-outbox>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 19px; HEIGHT: 23px" class="goog-inline-block hb-ui-grid-header-check"><SPAN aria-checked=false class="goog-checkbox goog-checkbox-unchecked" title="Select all tickets" role=checkbox tabIndex=0 yH="checkbox" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="58"></SPAN></DIV>
<DIV hideFocus style="WIDTH: 376px; HEIGHT: 23px" class="hb-ui-grid-header hb-ui-grid-header-horizontal goog-inline-block" tabIndex=0 unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="56">
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 2095px" class=hb-ui-grid-header-content unselectable="on" aH="0">
<TBODY unselectable="on">
<TR unselectable="on"><TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1i class=hb-ui-grid-column title=History unselectable="on" model="H">H</TD><TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1j class=hb-ui-grid-column title=Attachments unselectable="on" model="A">A</TD><TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 60px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1k class=hb-ui-grid-column title=Clone unselectable="on" model="C">C</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1l class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Ticket ID" unselectable="on" model="1">Ticket ID</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 542px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1m class=hb-ui-grid-column title=Title unselectable="on" model="109">Title</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1n class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Reported on" unselectable="on" model="115">Reported on</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 84px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1o class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Detected on" unselectable="on" model="118">Detected on</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 132px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1p class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Detected by" unselectable="on" model="119">Detected by</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 118px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1q class=hb-ui-grid-column title="System SW-Rev." unselectable="on" model="129">System SW-Rev.</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 126px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1r class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Integrated in version" unselectable="on" model="404">Integrated in version</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1s class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Tested in version" unselectable="on" model="507">Tested in version</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 31px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1t class=hb-ui-grid-column title=Result unselectable="on" model="504">Result</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 162px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1u class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Last change by user" unselectable="on" model="51">Last change by user</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 73px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1v class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Ticket state" unselectable="on" model="53">Ticket state</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 102px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1w class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Ticket owner" unselectable="on" model="76">Ticket owner</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 99px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1x class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Ticket step" unselectable="on" model="55"><SPAN class=hb-ui-grid-sort unselectable="on">▲</SPAN>Ticket step</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 86px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1y class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Last change date" unselectable="on" model="52">Last change date</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 64px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:1z class=hb-ui-grid-column title=Priority unselectable="on" model="215">Priority</TD><TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 23px" id=:20 class=hb-ui-grid-column title="Sequence of Activity" unselectable="on" model="68">Sequence of Activity</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
<DIV aria-haspopup=true style="DISPLAY: none" class="goog-inline-block hb-grid-menu-button" title="Overview options" role=button aria-activedescendant="" yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="60">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block hb-grid-menu-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block hb-grid-menu-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block hb-grid-menu-button-caption" unselectable="on"></DIV>
<DIV class="goog-inline-block hb-grid-menu-button-dropdown" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 416px; HEIGHT: 82px" class=hb-ui-grid-scrollarea unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="71">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 20px; HEIGHT: 64px" class=hb-ui-grid-pane unselectable="on">
<TABLE style="LINE-HEIGHT: 23px; BORDER-SPACING: 0; WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; OVERFLOW: hidden; hasLayout: -1" cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 15px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell><SPAN style="-webkit-user-select: none" class=hb-table-cell-check-box></SPAN></TD></TR>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 15px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell><SPAN style="-webkit-user-select: none" class=hb-table-cell-check-box></SPAN></TD></TR>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 15px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell><SPAN style="-webkit-user-select: none" class=hb-table-cell-check-box></SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 378px; HEIGHT: 64px" class=hb-ui-grid-pane unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="66">
<TABLE style="LINE-HEIGHT: 23px; BORDER-SPACING: 0; WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: separate; TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; OVERFLOW: hidden; hasLayout: -1" cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-calendar></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 25px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-attachment></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 60px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 50px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 110px" class=hb-table-cell>1797443</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 542px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 175px" class=hb-table-cell>[MAP]Unexisting street through Ta Phuk river</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 717px" class=hb-table-cell>2016-01-19</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 84px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 812px" class=hb-table-cell>2016-01-19</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 132px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 896px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 118px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1028px" class=hb-table-cell>152153.3.210</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 126px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1146px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1272px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 31px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1288px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 162px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1319px" class=hb-table-cell>IModoleev</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 73px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1481px" class=hb-table-cell>Categorized</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 102px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1554px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 99px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1656px" class=hb-table-cell>Concluding</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 86px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1755px" class=hb-table-cell>2016-01-26</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 64px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1841px" class=hb-table-cell>C(3)</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1905px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-calendar></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 25px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-attachment></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 60px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 50px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 110px" class=hb-table-cell>1780104</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 542px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 175px" class=hb-table-cell>[DI]Preview map for country list is not refreshing</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 717px" class=hb-table-cell>2015-12-15</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 84px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 812px" class=hb-table-cell>2015-12-15</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 132px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 896px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 118px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1028px" class=hb-table-cell>161153.3.210</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 126px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1146px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1272px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 31px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1288px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 162px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1319px" class=hb-table-cell>IModoleev</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 73px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1481px" class=hb-table-cell>Categorized</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 102px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1554px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 99px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1656px" class=hb-table-cell>Concluding</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 86px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1755px" class=hb-table-cell>2016-01-26</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 64px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1841px" class=hb-table-cell>C(3)</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1905px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
<TR style="LINE-HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 100%" class=hb-ui-grid-row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 0px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-calendar></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 25px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 25px" class=hb-table-cell>
<DIV class=hb-ui-attachment></DIV></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 60px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 50px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 110px" class=hb-table-cell>1774770</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 542px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 175px" class=hb-table-cell>Only one street is shown for postcode 0010(Oslo)</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 717px" class=hb-table-cell>2015-12-08</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 84px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 812px" class=hb-table-cell>2015-12-08</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 132px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 896px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 118px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1028px" class=hb-table-cell>101153.3.211</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 126px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1146px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1272px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 31px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1288px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 162px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1319px" class=hb-table-cell>IModoleev</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 73px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1481px" class=hb-table-cell>Categorized</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 102px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1554px" class=hb-table-cell>RBalan</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 99px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1656px" class=hb-table-cell>Concluding</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 86px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1755px" class=hb-table-cell>2016-01-26</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 64px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1841px" class=hb-table-cell>C(3)</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 1905px" class=hb-table-cell>&nbsp;</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 18px; HEIGHT: 64px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 398px" class=hb-grid-scroll-vertical unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="64">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 1px; HEIGHT: 92px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 378px; HEIGHT: 18px; TOP: 64px; LEFT: 20px" class=hb-grid-scroll-horizontal unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="65">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 2095px; HEIGHT: 1px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV hideFocus class="goog-toolbar goog-toolbar-horizontal" role=toolbar yH="toolbar" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="96">
<DIV id=:2d class="hb-toolbar-label goog-inline-block" tabIndex=0 unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="72">Mode:</DIV>
<DIV aria-haspopup=true id=:2i class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-menu-button" title="" role=button tabIndex=0 yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="74">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-menu-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-menu-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-menu-button-caption" unselectable="on">All</DIV>
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-menu-button-dropdown" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2j class="goog-toolbar-separator goog-inline-block" role=separator yH="separator" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2k class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="First page" role=button yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="77">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="icon hb-grid-first" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2l class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="Previous page" role=button yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="79">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="icon hb-grid-left" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2m class="hb-toolbar-label goog-inline-block" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="81">Page</DIV><INPUT style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2n class="hb-toolbar-editor goog-inline-block" value=1 maxLength=4 size=2 type=text closure_uid_7r0z52="83">
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2o class="hb-toolbar-label goog-inline-block" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="85">of 16</DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2p class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="Next page" role=button yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="87">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="icon hb-grid-right" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=:2q class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="Last page" role=button yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="89">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="icon hb-grid-last" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=:2r class="goog-toolbar-separator goog-inline-block" role=separator yH="separator" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV id=:2s class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title=Refresh role=button tabIndex=0 yH="button" unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="91">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box" unselectable="on">
<DIV class="icon icon hb-grid-refresh" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=:2t class="goog-toolbar-separator goog-inline-block" role=separator yH="separator" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV style="COLOR: black" id=:2u class="hb-toolbar-label goog-inline-block" tabIndex=0 unselectable="on" closure_uid_7r0z52="93">3 tickets found</DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

My full c# code is here:

```
using System.Threading;
namespace snippet
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://elvis.harman.com/");

            while (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            //textBox1.Text= this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[2].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Count.ToString();


            this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[2].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0].InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[2].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[1].InnerText = textBox2.Text;
            this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[2].Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].InvokeMember("click");

            //MessageBox.Show("Done!");


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://elvis.harman.com/cgi-bin/ticket?TID=" + txtID.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://elvis.harman.com/cgi-bin/ticket?TID=" + txtID.Text);
            //Thread.Sleep(2000);

            this.webBrowser1.Update();
            //var b = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ticketHeader").InnerHtml;

            // txtTitle.Text =  this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field_100");
            var codes = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gridBox").InnerHtml.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(m => m.Trim()).ToList();

            //search in code for the line that starts with " "
            var ticketLines = codes.Where(m => m.StartsWith("<TD style=\"WIDTH: 65px; HEIGHT: 22px; LEFT: 110px\" class=hb-table-cell>"));

            //create list in which will store the text filtered
            List<string> ticketTitles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in ticketLines)
            {   
                //select the line from which you want to start scrapping
                int y = codes.IndexOf(line);
                //ticket title
                ticketTitles.Add(codes[y + 1].Substring(codes[y + 1].IndexOf(">") + 1, codes[y + 1].Length - codes[y + 1].IndexOf(">") - 6));
                //created at
                ticketTitles.Add(codes[y+2].Substring(codes[y+2].IndexOf(">")+1, codes[y+2].Length - codes[y+2].IndexOf(">") - 6 )); 
            }



            //int x = 1;

        }
```

How can I reproduce this to reach to this code. it seems that is different than using inspect element in Chrome? Or how can I proceed further in this?

Thank you!

Comment: what is ur question?

Comment: Do you mean that You want to Generate a new Form or You already have a Form that you only want to extract some InnerHtml values to put inside your already created form? I am not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. You can do this with a simple WebApi or a harder way is to Serialize and extract innerHtml. Which I don't recommend.

Comment: Yes, i already have a form, but when i try to pass the info filtered into texbox, it doesn t show me anything